# jquery UI Highlight div not containing child spans properly

Tags: css, jquery-ui

```
<div class="ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info" style="float: left;margin-right: 0.3em;"></span>
    <span class="spanHeading" style="float: left;display: inline">ADMISSION TYPE</span>
    <span class="spanHeading" style="float: right">EXISTING ADMISSION TYPE</span>
<div>
```

i want to display `span` content inside `div`, but the Span Context display out of Highlight div.

Answer (score 0):

Not a CSS expert, but I think you need to [clear your floats](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html). For most browsers, I think just setting an `overflow` property will work:

```
div.clear {
    overflow:auto;
}​
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Xf2hq/